# OrderedDict reinitialisation: order is lost

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

My class is inherited from OrderedDict and I want to to reinitialise the dictionary. But simplified code below changes only values of keys - order of elements remains the same:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class Example(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self,d):
        OrderedDict.__init__(self,d)
        #something that should be done only once - at instance creation

    def reinit(self,d):
        OrderedDict.__init__(self,d)

d=Example([(1,1),(2,2)])
d.reinit([(2,20),(1,10)])

print(d) #Example([(1, 10), (2, 20)])
```

So the question is: what is happening inside `OrderedDict.__init__` here and is it supposed to work this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OrderedDict.__init__()` doesn't clear the dictionary. It merely uses the equivalent of `self.update()` to add the elements to the dictionary. All you did was add *already existing keys*.

You'd have to first remove those keys or clear the dictionary altogether:

```
def reinit(self, d):
    self.clear()
    OrderedDict.__init__(self, d)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> class Example(OrderedDict):
...     def reinit(self, d):
...         self.clear()
...         OrderedDict.__init__(self, d)
... 
>>> d=Example([(1,1),(2,2)])
>>> d.reinit([(2,20),(1,10)])
>>> print(d)
Example([(2, 20), (1, 10)])
```

You can always look at the source code for most Python library modules; the [`collections` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) links you to the [source code with the `OrdededDict` class](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l26).